# Why does Urchatz begin with a Vov?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada

In the passover Haggadah (in the schedule) the only word that has a Vav is Urchatz. Why? And if its connected to Kadesh why is it listed after Kadesh since usually you wash before kedusha?

Comment: Note that there are numerous variations of this poem.

Comment: Because the meter requires two syllables, which precludes רחיצה, for example, which wouldn't rhyme with יחץ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Yisroel Reisman writes,

> In the deeper meaning of Kadeish Ur'chatz it seems to be an inverted
>   expression. If we pride ourselves in the Seder of this evening then
>   Kadeish would mean to make yourself holy and Ur'chatz would mean to
>   wash yourself off of the Tumah that you have. If you want to clean
>   something you first get rid of the dirt and then you apply the shine.
>   It should be R'chatz V'Kadeish? We say Kadeish first and Rechitzah
>   second. That is Seder.   People think that to reach levels of Kedusha
>   that they must rid themselves of the Yeitzer Horas and get rid of all
>   the things that drag them down. We say on Pesach, no, just jump into
>   the Kedusha. Even if you feel unworthy and that the Yeitzer Hora is
>   dragging you down, Kadeish just jump into the Kedushah. Why?   That is
>   what happened on Pesach. Klal Yisrael still in the Mem Tes  Sharei
>   Tumah just jumped into Kedushah. There was no big Teshuvah movement at
>   the time. We see this from the Yam Suf where it is said Halalu Ovdei
>   Avoda Zorah V'halalu Ovdei Avoda Zorah. We know that a Shifcha at
>   the Yam Suf saw more of a prophecy than Yechezkel Ben Buzi. By
>   Pesach we tell people do what your forefathers did, just jump into the
>   Kedushah. After you jump into the Kedushah you can worry about
>   Ur'chatz the getting rid of your Yeitzer Horas.

Rav Reisman seems to be saying the vav in Ur'chatz is connecting it directly with Kadesh. Specifically say Kadesh without getting rid of the things which can drag a person down. Then after jumping into the Kedusha (Kadesh) you can work through Ur'chatz.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's alluding to the fact that the washing should take place immediately after *kiddush* so that there's no *hefsek* and it still qualifies as *kiddush bmakom seudah*.

(There is in any case a long period of time until the matzah is eaten, but it seems that the seder itself is not considered a *hefsek* in this regard. And perhaps this point was singled out as a potential *hefsek* because this is the point where many families do tend to take a break during the rest of the year).

Comment: During the rest of the year there's also a concern for makom seudah

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't mean that the rest of the year it's okay to take a break, just that many unfortunately do. If there was a poem for the rest of the year, it would also call it "urchatz" according to this theory.